# Golang AWS S3 : SignatureDoesNotMatch error while calling GetObjectRequest

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I am trying to create a pre-signed URL to view a document I want to include `IfMatch` constraint in `GetObjectInput` for the function `GetObjectRequest` to verify whether a document had tampered with or not. But When I include the constraint It shows an error as `SignatureDoesNotMatch`, my code is given below.

```
session, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String(<Region>)})
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
svc := s3.New(session)

req, output := svc.GetObjectRequest(&s3.GetObjectInput{
            Bucket:  aws.String(<BucketName>),
            Key:     aws.String(value[1]), // value = ["id","<Key>","<hash: ETag stored while uploading>"]
            IfMatch: aws.String(value[2]),
        })
urlStr, err := req.Presign(15 * time.Minute)
```

I am sure that value[2] contains the correct Hash/ETag. Any Idea how to include the `IfMatch` constraint in GetObjectRequest.

When going to the URL in urlStr I am getting an error as given in the screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: Does it work without the `IfMatch` parameter?

Comment: Are you passing in the `If-Match` header when performing the request to match the signed header?

Comment: @DanielFarrell it is working without ```IfMatch``` parameter, thank you for asking

Comment: @AnonCoward I am not passing ```If-Match```  header when performing the request explicitly, I am using Go AWS-SDK *(I am new to it)* function ```GetObjectRequest```, I think it automatically includes the header while requesting if not so can you please share any documentation if available, thank you for asking

Comment: Sorry, but no, the sdk signs the header, it doesn't include it in the request.  This is why you're seeing a signature mismatch:  The header you're providing in the request, without If-Match, doesn't match the signed version with it.  You'll need to include a If-Match HTTP header for the request to work with that presigned URL.  [The docs mention this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html#query-string-auth-v4-signing-example), "You can optionally add all other headers that you plan to include in your request", i.e., you include the headers in the request.